"identifier not found" while compiling for ARM64 with Visual Studio 2019
i am getting compiler errors "identifier not found" while compiling for ARM64 with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows x64 machine
This is seen for many identifiers eg: _InterlockedO64, ReadAcquire8, WriteRelease64.......
this project compiles properly for x64
what is the issue here not sure

I have checked in VS 2022 and those identifiers are defined when compiling for ARM64. You may need to update your compiler and/or the Windows SDK.

Is it dependent on VS 2022. Can it not be done with VS 2019.

I cannot answer that as I do not have a copy of the compiler and SDK that comes with VS 2019. But you can look for yourself by opening the "WinNT.h" header file in any editor and searching for those identifiers.

thank you.......i was looking for Visual studio 2019.  anyone please help

Then you need to do what I suggested and examine the "Winnt.h" header file to see if it actually contains definitions of those identifiers.

I noticed this issue a month or so ago in one of my 'regression' pipelines. The 10.0.26100.1882 servicing release of Windows SDK (26100) introduced these changes and now requires the VS 2022 toolchain for ARM64 on Windows Desktop "classic" development. This does not impact UWP for ARM64 on VS 2019.
The response from the MSVC compiler team is that VS 2022 ARM64 support is significantly better than VS 2019 ARM64 support, so they strongly recommend dropping VS 2019 for the ARM64 platform.
The only workaround for using VS 2019 to target ARM64 on Windows Desktop is to stick with Windows SDK (22621).

Thankyou for the answer Chuck.
inspite of moving to VS2022 i see the same compiler error.

Update- Tried with 10.0.26100.
But still seeing the same errors in VS 2002

Please add the exact text of the compiler diagnostics to your question.

C3861: 'ReadAcquire8' identifier not found
File: winnt.h
there are many similar errors from winnt.h & winbase.h
like 'ReadAcquire64' identifier not found
and so on

Did you mean VS 2022 or did you mean VS 2002? If using VS 2022, which Update are you using?

sorry. it is VS 2022
